# How to check if char **str is empty? (C)

Tags: c, string

In my C code. I have char **str and need to check if the string is empty. I wrote the following code as it works for char *str, but I got the error: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type in compiler and "segmentation fault" in running the compiled code. What's the correct way of checking if **str is empty? Thanks

```
char **str = "";

if (**str == 0)
   printf("it's an empty string\n");
```

Comment: `char **` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char` array. Your assignment won't work. I don't know of any way to always tell garbage from data; that's why `main()` comes with the number of arguments.

Comment: Do you know what's the type of a string in C?

Comment: Both of these answers are correct.
:)

Comment: @SeanPedersen: technically, `argc` is redundant since `argv[argc] == 0` (that is guaranteed, and no prior element of `argv` will be null, though an argument might be empty — a valid pointer to a null byte).  However, it is convenient to know how many arguments there are without having to count them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't remember reading that anywhere... ever. Thanks! (Still learning these at sign things - did that post to you inbox?)

Comment: @SeanPedersen: yes, your comment appeared in my 'inbox'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that `""` is not the address of a `char` pointer, which is what should be stored in `char **str`.  You're storing the address of a null byte and indeterminate following characters in `str` and then trying to treat that as an address — which is not a recipe for happiness.

Maybe you are thinking of:

```
char *data = "";
char **str = &data;

if (str == 0)       // Is str a null pointer (answer: no)
    …report that str is a null pointer…
if (*str == 0)      // Does str point at a null pointer (answer: no)
    …report that str points at a null pointer…
if (**str == '\0')  // Is the string pointed at empty (answer: yes)
    …report empty string…
```

Comment: yes, right, my problem is assigning "" to char **str. When I switched to char **str = &data; my "if (**str == 0)" works. Thank you

Comment: what's your difference between null and empty? Jonathan, thanks

Comment: A null pointer is represented by 0 in source code, but isn't formally required to be all bits zero in the hardware, even though that is by far the most common representation for a null pointer.  The empty string is represented by a valid pointer to a zero (null) byte, `'\0'`.  So, null is slightly ambiguous, though it most often means a null pointer and in the absence of a qualifier ('null byte'), mention of 'null' should be assumed to be a null pointer.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I am amazed by the fast replies, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 4):

`**str == 0` is perfectly fine to check whether `str` points to a pointer to an empty string. Your problem is that `char **str = "";` is illegal because `""` is not a pointer to a pointer.